# Cannot find module 'metro/src/lib/TerminalReporter' in expo react-native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

***Whenever I try to run npm start to start my project. It throws this error :***

[image]

***Package.json***

[image]

Any Idea how to get out of this?

I have also tried this:

- Deleted **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** and reinstalled using *npm install* but didn't work.

Comment: try `expo upgrade`. sometimes it helps

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who still runs into this issue. I came across it today, turns out running npm install didn't install the metro package. However, running yarn the metro package does get installed.

After running yarn the app builds, and starts as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by running:

```
npm install --save-dev metro
```

in the terminal. This installed `metro` locally.